Solana: `initializeUserMint` Function Fails with '_bn' Error Despite Matching Program ID
Question:
I'm developing a Solana program to allow users to initialise their own token mints. The program includes the initializeUserMint instruction, which works as expected when tested locally. However, when attempting to call this function from the client-side application, it fails with the error:
Token creation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_bn')

Key Details

Program ID Matches: The deployed program ID is correct and matches between the Rust program, the generated IDL, and the client application.
declare_id!("4XhFa2aZZh8L4ejKA44fy2RNTu1b4JRTChdoCp1VnonN");


Rust Function Implementation:
Here's the relevant Rust implementation of initializeUserMint:
pub fn initialize_user_mint(
    ctx: Context<InitializeUserMint>,
    name: Vec<u8>,
    symbol: Vec<u8>,
    initial_supply: u64,
) -> Result<()> {
    require!(name.len() <= 32, AmmError::InvalidArgument);
    require!(symbol.len() <= 10, AmmError::InvalidArgument);
    require!(initial_supply > 0, AmmError::InvalidInitialAmount);

    let mut name_fixed: [u8; 32] = [0; 32];
    let mut symbol_fixed: [u8; 10] = [0; 10];

    name_fixed[..name.len()].copy_from_slice(&name);
    symbol_fixed[..symbol.len()].copy_from_slice(&symbol);

    let user_mint_data = &mut ctx.accounts.user_mint_data;
    user_mint_data.creator = ctx.accounts.user.key();
    user_mint_data.mint_address = ctx.accounts.user_mint.key();
    user_mint_data.name = name_fixed;
    user_mint_data.symbol = symbol_fixed;
    user_mint_data.initial_supply = initial_supply;

    let cpi_accounts = token::MintTo {
        mint: ctx.accounts.user_mint.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.user_token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts);
    token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, initial_supply)?;

    Ok(())
}


IDL Entry:
The IDL includes the initializeUserMint instruction with all the necessary arguments and accounts:
{
    "name": "initializeUserMint",
    "docs": [
        "Initialise a user-owned token mint with a given name, symbol, and initial supply.",
        "The created tokens are minted into the user's associated token account immediately."
    ],
    "accounts": [
        {
            "name": "userMintData",
            "isMut": true,
            "isSigner": false
        },
        {
            "name": "userMint",
            "isMut": true,
            "isSigner": true
        },
        {
            "name": "userTokenAccount",
            "isMut": true,
            "isSigner": false
        },
        {
            "name": "user",
            "isMut": true,
            "isSigner": true
        },
        {
            "name": "systemProgram",
            "isMut": false,
            "isSigner": false
        },
        {
            "name": "tokenProgram",
            "isMut": false,
            "isSigner": false
        },
        {
            "name": "associatedTokenProgram",
            "isMut": false,
            "isSigner": false
        },
        {
            "name": "rent",
            "isMut": false,
            "isSigner": false
        }
    ],
    "args": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "bytes"
        },
        {
            "name": "symbol",
            "type": "bytes"
        },
        {
            "name": "initialSupply",
            "type": "u64"
        }
    ]
}


Client Code:
Here's the JavaScript function calling the instruction:
import { BN } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { PublicKey, Keypair, SystemProgram, SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { utf8 } from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/bytes";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, getAssociatedTokenAddress } from "@solana/spl-token";
import idl from "../../../utils/idl/solana_amm.json";

export async function createUserToken({ provider, name, symbol, supply }) {
    try {
        const programId = new PublicKey("4XhFa2aZZh8L4ejKA44fy2RNTu1b4JRTChdoCp1VnonN");
        const program = new Program(idl, programId, provider);

        const nameBytes = utf8.encode(name);
        const symbolBytes = utf8.encode(symbol);

        const [userMintPda] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [Buffer.from("user-mint"), provider.wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(), nameBytes],
            programId
        );

        const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
        const userTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintKeypair.publicKey, provider.wallet.publicKey);

        const supplyBN = new BN(supply);

        await program.methods
            .initializeUserMint([...nameBytes], [...symbolBytes], supplyBN)
            .accounts({
                userMintData: userMintPda,
                userMint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
                userTokenAccount: userTokenAccount,
                user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                rent: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            })
            .signers([mintKeypair])
            .rpc();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Token creation failed:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}


Error:
Despite all configurations seemingly correct, the client logs this error:
Token creation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_bn')


Debugging Steps Taken:

Verified the program ID matches between the deployed program, IDL, and client code.
Confirmed initializeUserMint appears in the IDL and is callable through the Anchor CLI.
Checked all account initialisation and arguments are aligned.



What could be causing this error? Is it an issue with the way BN is being used or the encoding of arguments?

It's tough to tell without more info, but likely one of the PublicKeys passed into your function is invalid -- the _bn field is stored directly on the PublicKey at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/eb3b362c4e03098be2b1af432cd0864879c6886c/src/publickey.ts#L50, so probably one of those is incorrect or undefined.

The error likely occurs due to incorrect initialization of the BN object for supply; ensure supply is a valid numeric value and passed as new BN(Number(supply)).
